# Why does the combine operator of flow works with arrays?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Why does the combine operator of flow works with arrays(instead of list or iterator)?

From source code:

```
public inline fun <reified T, R> combine(
    flows: Iterable<Flow<T>>,
    crossinline transform: suspend (Array<T>) -> R
): Flow<R> {
    val flowArray = flows.toList().toTypedArray()
    return flow {
        combineInternal(
            flowArray,
            arrayFactory = { arrayOfNulls(flowArray.size) },
            transform = { emit(transform(it)) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's just for convenience, because most `combine...` methods use `vararg flows: Flow<T>` parameter and call `combineInternal()` function, and it is convenient just to pass `flows` to `combineInternal()` method without converting it to another data structure. Example of a method, which accepts `vararg flows: Flow<T>` parameter:

```
public inline fun <reified T, R> combine(
    vararg flows: Flow<T>,
    crossinline transform: suspend (Array<T>) -> R
): Flow<R> = flow {
    combineInternal(flows, { arrayOfNulls(flows.size) }, { emit(transform(it)) })
}
```

Comment: yes seems so. Didn't know spread operator just works with arrays.Thanks!